# How to copy video or image file from one location into another using media store api for android 11

Tags: java, android, sdk, mediastore

```
public boolean moveFilesToSentPath(Context context, String type, String filePath, String fileName) {
        String folderPath = getFolderPath(type);
        File dir;
       /* if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {

            dir = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES *//*+ "/" + fileName*//*);
        }else {*/
            dir = new File(this.context.getFilesDir().toString() + "/" + folderPath); //        }
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
            File nomediaFile = new File(dir.getAbsoluteFile(), ".nomedia");
            try {
                if (!nomediaFile.exists()) {
                    nomediaFile.createNewFile();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        File from = new File(filePath);
        File to = new File(dir + "/" + fileName);
        Log.v(TAG, "moveFilesToSentPathFrom= " + from);
        Log.v(TAG, "moveFilesToSentPathTo= " + to);
        if (from.exists()) {
            try {
                FileUtils.copyFile(from, to);
                return true;
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

1. I want to copy video file from its original location to my own created destination i.e. like (Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES + "/" + "video" + "/"+fileName) and then access the file from destination. And also plz elaborate the media store api usage for saving file at specific location
2. The above code is for api level lower than 30, but need solution for android 11 api level 30 as we can't access storage due to security reasons but instead they provide with media store api, I don't have much idea with media store api. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: There is no mediastore used in the code you posted. And why did you post all that code?

Comment: You could better start your post by just telling where you have your file. And then where you wanna copy your file to using  the mediastore.

Comment: @blackapps I updated the question, Let me know if any thing else needed regarding description or code.

Comment: You did not provide full path of original. Nor from destination.